# Mutual exclusion with UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concurrency, react-hooks

I have a component with some different states: all the states are separate views of one object, and they are not mutually exclusive.

Imagine a class with a dozen of scholar: they all have characteristics that I describe with states: eye color, hair color, gender and so on.

So, I can select 'all the scholars with brown hair AND male' or 'all with blue eyes and female' and so on.

So I have all these states that act as filters.

But there is another state, say state1, which represent a specific scholar, say 'John Park' or 'Sarah Fawcett'.

When this filter is activated there is just one possible answer, and all the other filters vanish

```
const [specificPerson,setSpecificPerson]=useState(false);
const [hairColor,setHairColor]=useState(false);
const [eyeColor,setEyeColor]=useState(false);
const [gender,setGender] = useState(false);

const allScholars = [array of all scholars];
const [selectedScholars, setSelectedSCholars] = useState([]);
```

then I have 2 useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
     setHairColor(false);
     setEyeColor(false);
     setGender(false);
}, [specificPerson] )


useEffect(() => {

     set list = [];
     if (hairColor || eyeColor || gender) {
        list.add(allScholars.filter (byHairColor)
        list.add(allScholars.filter (byEyeColor)
        list.add(allScholars.filter (byGender)
     } else {
        list.add(specificPerson);
    
     setSelectedScholars(list.unique);

}, [allScholars, selectedScholars, specificPerson, hairColor, eyeColor, gender, setSelectedScholars] )

return <>selectedScholars.map(each .....) </>
```

now, the current state of my application is as follow:

```
hairColor = brown
eyeColor = false
gender = false
specificPerson = false
```

All the sholars with brown hair are collected into the `selectedScholars` and then `rendered`.

Then, the event `setSpecificPerson("John Doe")` occurs.
"John Doe" should be rendered and all the other scholars should disappear because of the first useEffect.

What really happens is just another movie:

1. the first useEffect fires because of `specificPerson`
2. then the second useEffect fires because of `specificPerson`, but `hairColor` is not yet changed and is still `brown`, because  of the queue.
3. the `specificPerson` is not rendered.

I hope this example be more realistic of the previous one.

Comment: Instead of state 1 to n as separate variables, why not use an array? This example seems sort of contrived -- I recommend adding a bit of real-world context to better motivate whatever you're trying to do. [There may be a better way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Comment: Why are you listing `state1` as a dependency of the second effect when the second effect doesn't use it for anything?

Comment: Separately, if they're mutually-exclusive, I would probably store them differently. For instance, a number or character or object that represents the currently-selected option. It only complicates things to store the same information repeatedly (`[true, false, false]` when the `true` in the first position tells you that you have `false, false` in the second and third).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: it was only to limit the complexity of the example. Of course it is used in the UseEffect

Comment: @PaoloDiPietro - That's an important thing to show, then. Without it, the example makes no sense, and we can't help you with the underlying problem.

Comment: Setting filter values is one thing, but storing the filtered data also in state, this is redundant and is easily derived from the array of scholars and any current filtering values. It's anti-pattern in React to store derived state in state, use the state and compute/render the derived state out to JSX, i.e. `allScholars.filter(/* apply filtering conditions here */).map(scholar => ....)`. If it's computationally expensive then memoize the computed derived "state".

Comment: @DrewReese well Drew, I made some changes and your suggestio resolved my problem. I would add a new question:  I have a `axios.get(path)
            .then((res) => {
               setScholars([res.data]);
            })`
and 'const [scholars, setScholars] = useState([])` is an immutable state.

How can I memoize that result?

Comment: @PaoloDiPietro I don't memoizing the state is necessary, the `scholars` state is already a stable reference and the state value won't change unless you make a call to `setScholars` with a new value. If you meant memoizing the filtered state then this is done using the `useMemo` hook, i.e. `const filteredScholars = useMemo(() => { /* filtering business logic */ }, [scholars, /* ...filters, and any other dependencies */]);`. `filteredScholars` will be a stable reference and only be recomputed when one of the dependencies updates.